# Matplotlib not displaying figures

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

This must be a really basic question: I am trying to use Matplotlib. Here's the basic example from the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I have tried this in `ipython`, `bpython` and the default interpreter (Ubuntu 10.10, 64 bit) and all I get are messages like:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x3f14a90>]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're missing `plt.show()` to order matplotlib to show a window with the graph.

Comment: or `plt.savefig` to save the result in an image file

Comment: OMG, for some annoying reason when running Spyder I never needed this, but I didn't understand why Eclipse didn't **show** my plots...

Comment: Ivo: Because spyder starts mpl in ion() mode.

Answer (score 6):

In its default configuration, matplotlib needs to be told to render.  That's what plt.show() does.

Matplotlib also has an interactive mode that can be useful when you're working interactively and want  your plotting commands to happen immediately.  The easiest way to use this is by opening an ipython session with the -pylab option.  http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/shell.html